# Shortcodes in Shopify no longer working when using render instead of include

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm currently using shortcodes in Shopify via [this customization](https://github.com/culturekings/shopify-shortcodes). Shopify updated liquid to deprecate include and replaced it with render. This seems to break all of my embeds. I have them on pages and product descriptions, enabling using:

```
{% render 'shortcode' load: page.content %}
```

It used to be:

```
{% include 'shortcode' load: page.content %}
```

Now that I use render, I just get an error on page "include usage is not allowed in this context"

Does the render call change to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few differences with the render tag in comparison to the include:

1. You can't use include inside render tag (like in your case)
2. You must pass all variables to the render tag as arguments, it can't read them if you defined them outside of it and don't pass them.
3. Variables defined in the render tag are not accessible outside of it.

These are the main differences, so you will need to update your snippet to use only render tags and pass the appropriate variables to it.

Comment: It makes sense to me that something is not passing into the new render tag. I'm unsure of how to do that or know what they are supposed to be. Looking at the github link, is there any way to easily tell what should be added to the tag?

Comment: > You can use include inside render tag (like in your case)
I think you meant that "You can _not_ use include inside render tag"?

Comment: @DaveB you are right. Callmedpit you will need to test the code, there are too many assigns I don't know what is passing to the shortcode and what not.

Comment: @drip Yeah, I see what you mean, how would I go about figuring it out? To clarify, the new call would be something like this, right:?

{% render 'shortcode' load: page.content, keys: keys, keysFinal: keysFinal %}

But literally passing everything that would need to get passed? I just have no idea how to figure out what needs to be passed. I could just keep using the include for now, would that be badeven though it's depricated?

Comment: You can still use includes, they won't die soon or a lot of themes will just stop working, which will be bad rep for Shopify. The provided render method is correct indeed, but you have to debug it yourself since there are just too many variables to look into it myself.